# Moving graph in windows form

Tags: winforms, graph

I have two arraylist, x[],y[]. Suppose :

```
x[0]=  1, y[0]=2,

x[1]=  3, y[1]=3,

x[2]=  4, y[2]=6,

x[3]=  4, y[3]=9,

x[4]=  7, y[4]=22,

x[5]= -4, y[5]=5,

..............
```

in time delay of 10 sec, the graph goes [0] to [1] and then it goes on in same delay.

How i represent the graph? I think 3d graph is must here. But how do i use it in .Net winform?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a component to visuialize the data as a graph.

Check out [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422), they are a good option.